# Resizing an Image If it is bigger than X via Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder with some images in it, and I have a console application which will resize pictures, I want to write a batch script that will check every image and if it size is bigger than 250KB then it resizes them,

```
for every file in root
if file > 250KB
app.exe resize file
next file
```

how to do that via batch script?

Comment: Can you use PowerShell instead of cmd? You could do `ls *.* | where-object {$_.length -gt 256000}` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
for %f in (C:\*.*) do @if %~zf gtr 256000 @app.exe %f
```

Although note that inside of a bat/cmd file, you have to escape the `%`:

```
for %%f in (C:\*.*) do @if %%~zf gtr 256000 @app.exe %%f
```

If you need to do more, you can use brackets to do something like this:

```
for %%f in (C:\*.*) do @if %%~zf gtr 256000 (
   @app.exe %%f
   @echo Launched %%f
)
```

However, I'm not sure if this helps you, because you want to wait for the application to exit before you delete the file.

Comment: Thanks it is working like a charm, But If I want to do two commands if the if condition is true what will be the code, for example I want to add Del %%f after resizing, I tried to but codes in a block after if, but it is not working :(